# Sandcrawler, real or fake?

Tags: star-wars, props, a-new-hope

In the Star Wars movie "A New Hope", there were some small creatures called Jawas on the planet Tatooine. They were using a big vehicle and its name is **Sandcrawler**. So my question is, did makers of the movie actually build a big vehicle as they show in the movie or is it just a little prop vehicle showing as big (what will be actual size)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both. [A Miniature for wide shots of the moving sandcrawler](http://www.originalprop.com/blog/2008/07/12/ebay-original-star-wars-jawa-sandcrawler-statistical-authentication/), and a partially built full size version for the close up shots with people:

> From page 18 of The Best of The Lucasfilm Archives:
>
> > Off-the-shelf parts are an important part of big-movie model making.  The sandcrawler craft used by the Jawas to scour the flatlands for minerals and plunder, utilized four store-bought panzer tank tracks at its four corners.  **The final sandcrawler model was a fully motorized, radio-controlled vehicle three feet long and constructed of birch plywood covered with plastic and detailing.**  It was built with such powerful motors that its radio operators could make the sandcrawler pop a wheelie, although when the cameras rolled the miniature vehicle only had to lumber over the Tatooine wasteland.

Please note:

> The following images are from page 60 of Star Wars Chronicles:
>
> > **Only the lower part of the full-scale sandcrawler was actually constructed for filming.  Matte paintings were used to complete the vehicle, and a radio-controlled model was used for shooting in the California desert.**  The full-scale sandcrawler was two stories high and 27 meters long.  The completed model measured 56 x 125 x 66 cm.

[image]